# How to keep the session active when redirecting from domain to subdomain in Express js/

Tags: node.js, session, express, session-cookies, mean-stack

I am working on an Express project(MEAN). i have my login/register page at myDomain.com and on login i want to redirect the user to user.myDomain.com . I am storing the session in MongoDb using session storage module. I can redirect the user to the subdomain but since the session is not maitained in between the domain and subdomain.. it redirects user to the login page.
I have looked and tried everything from

[Using Express and Node, how to maintain a Session across subdomains/hostheaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071969/using-express-and-node-how-to-maintain-a-session-across-subdomains-hostheaders)
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/125
[Maintaining login session across subdomains in nodejs mongostore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626058/maintaining-login-session-across-subdomains-in-nodejs-mongostore)

But i am still lost and could not find a proper solution for thise.
Can you please help me.

**Edit:**
I did this but id did not help me.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static('../app'));

app.use(session({
  secret:appConfig.SECRET,
  resave:false,
  saveUninitialized:true,
  domain: '.myDomain.com',
  store: sessionstore.createSessionStore({
      type: 'mongodb',
      host: 'localhost',         // optional
      port: 27017,               // optional
      dbName: 'MyDataBase',       // optional
      collectionName: 'sessions',// optional
      timeout: 10000             // optional
      // authSource: 'authedicationDatabase',        // optional
      // username: 'technicalDbUser',                // optional
      // password: 'secret'                          // optional
      // url: 'mongodb://user:pass@host:port/db?opts // optional
  }),
  cookie: {
         path: '/',
         domain: '.myDomain.com',
         maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 24 // 24 hours
     }
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem before.
Maybe you could have a try like this:

```
  app.use(session({
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
    domain:'.dreamon.so' // That's what you need.
  },
  store: new RedisStore({
    host: settings.redis.HOST,
    port: settings.redis.PORT
  }),
  secret: settings.session.SECRET,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

But remember to clear browser cookie before you make an other test.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the same using session store module but it did not help me.Please check the edit to find what i did.

Comment: So you are sure you checked the cookie that is stored in your browser, and no cookie under user.myDomain.com, right? Could you please paste those code about redirect to login page and user.myDomain.com ?

Comment: I used $window.location  = "http://user.myDomain.com to redirect user from client side on getting the response from node upon login.