# Redirect to login page after session timeout using nodejs, expressjs and reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, express-session

i have node and react application. for middleware i am using expressjs.

i am trying to redirect to login page after session time out. i am using `express-session` for authentication, i am able to get session timeout but not able to redirect to login page.

My login url is `http://localhost:8009/login` which is implemented in react js for ui part.
`app.use('/', login);` router in node and expressjs

below is my code.

```
var session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
    secret: 'Test Service',
    name: "test",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave:false,
    cookie: {
        //maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        path: '/login',
        maxAge: 1 * 10 * 60 * 1000, 
        overwrite: false    
    }
}));
```

can anyone help me on this.
i have also checked below urls but not able to get the solutions.

[How to keep the session active when redirecting from domain to subdomain in Express js/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119380/how-to-keep-the-session-active-when-redirecting-from-domain-to-subdomain-in-expr)
https://gitlab.com/dinh.dich/express-session-expire-timeout#README

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, here are two options you have

1 - if you are talking about session and redirecting if there is no session :

Create a function in your router as such :

```
module.exports.home = (req,res)=>{
if(!req.session.user){
    //index is the main page without any session
    res.render('index');
}
else{
    //render to a different page
}
};
```

Hopefully this will give you a better idea. Good luck !

Comment: i have tried this but is there any json key or attribute present by which i can redirect to other page ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you give an example of what u mean

Comment: `cookie: {
        path: '/login',
        maxAge: 1 * 10 * 60 * 1000, 
        overwrite: false, anyKey: '/redirectPtah'
    }` please check `anyKey: '/redirectPtah'`. is there any key present for redirection ?

Comment: Well , imo that wouldn't work because those are properties of the cookie object,meaning even if could do anykey: '/redirectpath' , that is still not associated with the maxage. The properties are independent of each other

Comment: Also even if you could do it, your code wouldn't be clean, it's a better practice to handle routing through express routing

Comment: Hi @SangramBadi if your code for this question is on github then please provide a link, it'll be very helpful. I'm trying to create an application using Nodejs And Reactjs which has sessions and cookies and i'm unable to find a good resource to learn from

Comment: sorry @mk1024, it's not possible to give access, because it's our organization's application. if you want me to create like this application you can check my link also https://www.fiverr.com/sangrambadi/create-restful-api-and-ui-for-you-using-nodejs?arrived_from_manage_gigs=true&display_share=true